# Spark sortMergeJoin is not changing to shuffleHashJoin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to force spark to use ShuffleHashJoin by disabling BroadcastHashJoin and SortMergeJoin, but spark is always using SortMergeJoin.

I am using spark version 2.4.3

```
object ShuffleHashJoin {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("ShuffleHashJoin")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

/*
* Disable auto broadcasting of table and SortMergeJoin
*/
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 0)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", false)

import spark.implicits._
val dataset = Seq(
  (0, "playing"),
  (1, "with"),
  (2, "ShuffledHashJoinExec")).toDF("id", "token")

dataset.join(dataset, Seq("id"), "inner").foreach(_ => ())

// infinite loop to keep the program running to check Spark UI at 4040 port.
while (true) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides setting  `spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin` to `false` Spark has to validate the following: ([source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L260))

1. That a single partition should be small enough to build a hash table

```
canBuildLocalHashMap(right || left)
  |-> plan.stats.sizeInBytes < conf.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold * conf.numShufflePartitions
```

You have programmatically set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to 0, so it always evaluates to `false`.

2. That one side of the join is much smaller than other

   > The cost to build hash map is higher than sorting, we should only build hash map on a table that is much smaller than other one. Since we does not have the statistic for number of rows, use the size of bytes here as estimation.

```
muchSmaller(right, left) || muchSmaller(left, right) 
 |-> a.stats.sizeInBytes * 3 <= b.stats.sizeInBytes
```

In your example, we need to do several things to make it work:

1. Change auto broadcast threshold, to some small value
   `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 2)`
2. Make one side of the join at least `x3` bigger

And the working example:

```
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 2)
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", false)

    import spark.implicits._
    val dataset = Seq(
      (0, "playing"),
      (1, "with"),
      (2, "ShuffledHashJoinExec")).toDF("id", "token")

    val right = Seq(
      (0, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (1, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (2, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (3, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (4, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (5, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (6, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (7, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (8, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
      (9, "asdfghjklzxcvb"),
    )
      .toDF("id", "token")

    val joined = dataset.join(right, Seq("id"), "inner")
    joined.explain(true)

*(1) Project [id#5, token#6, token#15]
+- ShuffledHashJoin [id#5], [id#14], Inner, BuildLeft
   :- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#5, 200)
   :  +- LocalTableScan [id#5, token#6]
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#14, 200)
      +- LocalTableScan [id#14, token#15]
```

Comment: The function `muchSmaller` has been slightly updated since Spark 3.3.0. It no longer uses a hard-coded 3 but a multiplier set by `spark.sql.shuffledHashJoinFactor`, which defaults to 3. These functions were also refactored into a different class. The updated link to source code is `https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/joins.scala`